# Issue with exporting sas output by ods to latex (overleaf

Tags: sas, latex, ods

im having some difficulties with running some sas output in my .tex file

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

%    Generated by SAS
%    http://www.sas.com

\usepackage{sas}

% Set page layout
\geometry{top=1in, left=1in, right=1in, bottom=1in}
\geometry{nohead, nofoot}

\begin{document}

\sasproctitle[c]{The SURVEYMEANS Procedure}
\sascontents[1]{The Surveymeans Procedure}
\sascontents[2]{Data Summary}


\begin{sastable}[c]{lr}\hline
   \multicolumn{2}{|S{header}{c}|}{Data Summary}
\\\hline
\endhead
   \multicolumn{1}{|S{rowheader}{l}|}{Number of Observations} & 
   \multicolumn{1}{|S{data}{r}|}{2138}
\\\hline
\end{sastable}

\sascontents[2]{Statistics}


\begin{sastable}[c]{llrrrrr}\hline
   \multicolumn{7}{|S{header}{c}|}{Statistics}
\\\hline
   \multicolumn{1}{|S{header}{l}|}{Variable} & 
   \multicolumn{1}{|S{header}{l}|}{Label} & 
   \multicolumn{1}{|S{header}{r}|}{N} & 
   \multicolumn{1}{|S{header}{r}|}{Mean} & 
   \multicolumn{1}{|S{header}{r}|}{Std Error {\newline} of Mean} & 
   \multicolumn{2}{|S{header}{c}|}{95\% CL for Mean}
\\\hline
\endhead
   \multicolumn{1}{|S{rowheader}{l}|}{vteurmmb} & 
   \multicolumn{1}{|S{data}{l}|}{Would vote for [country] to remain member of European Union or leave} & 
   \multicolumn{1}{|S{data}{r}|}{2138} & 
   \multicolumn{1}{|S{data}{r}|}{1.172123} & 
   \multicolumn{1}{|S{data}{r}|}{0.008166} & 
   \multicolumn{1}{|S{data}{r}|}{1.15610967} & 
   \multicolumn{1}{|S{data}{r}|}{1.18813729}
\\\hline
\end{sastable}


\pagebreak

\sasproctitle[c]{The SURVEYMEANS Procedure}
\sascontents[2]{Distribution of vteurmmb}
\sascontents[3]{Summary Panel}
\end{document}
```

This is my code and i get the following error: sas.sty file not found. I hope that you can help with the issue. This is my code and i get the following error: sas.sty file not found. I hope that you can help with the issue

Comment: Did it ever work? What did you change?

Comment: No it still doesnt work

Comment: Is this LaTex code that is supposed to call SAS?  if it never worked how do you know it is even possible?  Or is this output generated by SAS code?  If so then post the SAS code.  Note the error message looks to me like it means that the `\usepackage` command is not finding the package.